# Проблема с Delphi и Access: EDatabaseError: Field not Found!

Tags: access, delphi

Имеется проект на delphi который работает с БД access. Я переименовал одно поле из столбца таблицы access, сменил его имя также на новое во всех местах проекта где оно есть, во всех SQL вызовах. И при вызове ADOQuery, который должен использовать его имя, с помощью ADOQuery.Open, я получаю ошибку Delphi и Access: EDatabaseError: Field not Found, причем имя поля, которое значится ненайденным-старое и нигде не используется больше! В чем может быть проблема? ? Может обновить как-то проект надо, в Access я нажимал кнопку "Обновить всё" - не помогает. При возврате к старому имени всё хорошо работает.

Comment: нужно отрефрешить контейнеры таблиц и запросов - jet не всегда понимает, что база изменилась.

Comment: А как это сделать, можно поподробнее?

Comment: @Андрей Бобков, если не знаете как, то можно просто перезагрузить машину. А вообще в документации должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Expert](/users/6/expert)](/users/6/expert), добрался до компьютера, освежил память. то, что я имел в виду, относилось к использованию Jet через DAO, для Delphi может немного отличаться (к тому же, не вполне понятно, какой провайдер использует автор - хорошо, если это Jet OLEDB). В частности, при использовании ADODB для подобных операций обычно используется ADOX, вот пример кода из asp:

```
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.open conString
Set adox = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
adox.ActiveConnection = cn
adox.Tables(tbl).Columns(col).Name = newName
adox.Tables.Refresh
Set adox = nothing
cn.close: set cn = nothing
```